# when configured in xml file, does log4net allow to specify the log file name inside the function call?

Tags: c#, log4net

In C# code, I want create a log file for each each method in my application, while normally only 1 log file is created per application. I need to specify the log file name in my method call and if its not created I create a new file and if it exists i just append the messages to the existing file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking this out and see if it helps:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200627120503/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/rgupta/archive/2009/03/03/dynamic-log-filenames-with-log4net.aspx)

Comment: thnx 4 d reply, it does dynamically create log file but its null.log and its still one log file since the context properties will be set before we instantiate the logger. correct me if i'm wrong plz